# Character won't jump Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i am making my first 3d game in Unity. I made a basic player controller and all the controls work fine except the jump. so i made the keybind for jumping the spacebar, but when you press it doesn't do anything.

The code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("movement")]
    public float moveSpeed;

    public float groundDrag;

    public float jumpForce;
    public float jumpCooldown;
    public float airMultiplier;
    bool readyToJump;

    [Header("Keybinds")]
    public KeyCode jumpkey = KeyCode.Space;

    [Header("Ground Check")]
    public float playerHeight;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;
    bool grounded;

    public Transform orientation;

    float horizontalInput;
    float verticalInput;

    UnityEngine.Vector3 moveDirection;

    Rigidbody rb;


    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rb.freezeRotation = true;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        //ground check
        grounded = Physics.Raycast(transform.position, UnityEngine.Vector3.down, playerHeight  * 0.5f + 0.2f, whatIsGround);

        MyInput();
        speedControl();

        //handle drag
        if (grounded)
            rb.drag = groundDrag;
        else
        
            rb.drag = 0;
        
            
            
        
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        MovePlayer();
    }

    private void MyInput()
    {
        horizontalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        verticalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        //when to jump
        if(Input.GetKey(jumpkey) && readyToJump && grounded)
        {
            readyToJump = false;

            Jump();

            Invoke(nameof(ResetJump), jumpCooldown);
        }
    }

    private void MovePlayer()
    {
        // calculate movement direction
        moveDirection = orientation.forward * verticalInput + orientation.right * horizontalInput;
        
        // on ground
        if(grounded)
            rb.AddForce(moveDirection.normalized * moveSpeed * 10f,ForceMode.Force);

        // in air
        else if(!grounded)  
            rb.AddForce(moveDirection.normalized * moveSpeed * 10f * airMultiplier,ForceMode.Force);


    }

    private void speedControl()
    {
        UnityEngine.Vector3 flatVel = new UnityEngine.Vector3(rb.velocity.x, 0f, rb.velocity.z);

        //limit velocity if needed
        if(flatVel.magnitude > moveSpeed)
        {
            UnityEngine.Vector3 limitedVel = flatVel.normalized * moveSpeed;
            rb.velocity = new UnityEngine.Vector3(limitedVel.x, rb.velocity.y, limitedVel.z);
        }
    }

    private void Jump()
    {
        // reset y velocity
        rb.velocity = new UnityEngine.Vector3(rb.velocity.x, 0f, rb.velocity.z);

        rb.AddForce(transform.up * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }
    private void ResetJump()
    {
        readyToJump = true;
    }
}
```

[The Player Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWB3C.png)

So i am searching for a fix but I cant find it, because i'm completely new to Unity and c#

Comment: so, when you debugged it, what did you find? does it run all the things you thought in the order you thought, did trhe jump force happen, are you sure its enough?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't initialize the `readyToJump` variable. By default a `bool` is set to `false`. Since it starts out `false` and the only code that sets it `ture` is behind the jump condition `Input.GetKey(jumpkey) && readyToJump && grounded` that is always `false` you cannot jump.

Initialize `bool readyToJump = true;` and it should work.